# How to filter data in R object so it only shows certain species?

Tags: r, metadata, phyloseq

Here is the code I am currently using after importing my OTU table, metadata, taxonomy and tree into R as one object. The issue I have is in the last line, I keep getting the error "Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent"

```
physeq = phyloseq(OTU, TAX, META, phy_tree)
library(phyloseq)
tps  = transform_sample_counts(physeq, function(x) x / sum(x) )
ftps = filter_taxa(physeq, function(x) {sum(x >0)>1}, TRUE)
psfirm = subset_taxa(physeq, Phylum==“Firmicutes”)
```

Comment: Just additional info. For me it was hard to install the `phyloseq` package. With this code it works. `if(!requireNamespace("BiocManager")){
  install.packages("BiocManager")
}
BiocManager::install("phyloseq")`

Comment: Your current example is not reproducible, so it is currently difficult to help pinpoint the error. Consider adding the following info: 1) Where the error occurs (does it occur at line 1, or 5?). 2) Loading libraries before code (I'm guessing the first line depends on the second line being executed). 3) Add example data, that reproduces your error using `dput(data)` (where data is a small [sub] dataset). The last part is crucial in most questions, if you want to receive good answers.

Comment: I think you should use straight quotes in the last line : `Phylum=="Firmicutes"` instead of `Phylum==“Firmicutes”`.